# What trig identities are important for calculus?

Tags: trigonometry

In preparation for calculus, I am learning trig identities, but there are a LOT of them, including the Pythagorean, cofunction, reciprocal, quotient, sum and difference, double and half angle identities; there are others, such as the sum-to-product, product-to-sum, and the reduction identities. My question is that is it worth learning the latter identities (sum-to-product, product-to-sum, and the reduction, etc.) for calculus, or is it merely a waste of time?

Comment: In my opinion I would say that learning *why* those identities are true and how to prove those identities is more important than learning the full list.  I would personally suggest learning that $\sin(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$.  Many of the other identities are able to be found by manipulating this (*though admittedly working with complex numbers if you are new to it can add confusion*).

Comment: Another route to proving such identities quickly is to recall that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and manipulating this, and recalling that after manipulations that the real parts of each side must equal as well as the imaginary parts must equal.  For instance $\cos(x+y)+i\sin(x+y)=e^{ix+iy}=e^{ix}e^{iy}=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$ giving that $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$ by looking at the real terms as well as that $\sin(x+y)=\cos(x)\sin(y)+\sin(x)\cos(y)$

Comment: Be able to recall sum and difference. Everything else follows without too much hassle; I never spent time memorising the identities as I could deduce whatever I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three:

$$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$$

$$\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$$

$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$$

If you divide $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ by $\cos^2 x$, you the the Pythagorean identity for $\tan x $ and $\sec x$.   If you divide it by $\sin^2 x$ you the the Pythagorean identity for $\cot x$ and $\csc x$.  So three identities for the price of one.

It's good to know $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$ because there are lots of problems where you see things like $\sin x \cos x$ and you need to change it to $\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$.

By applying the Pythagorean identity to the last one we get

$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = 1-2\sin^2 x = 2\cos^x -1$$

so again, three identities for the price of one.  Further, you can solve the last two equations to get the very useful

$$\cos^2 x = \frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}, \sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$

so really five identities for the price of one.

You'll pick up others as you go, but if you add the sum and difference of angles formulae for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, you can probably quickly derive whatever else you need.